# Mongo: is it possible to satisfy "and" condition on two documents

Tags: mongodb, logical-operators

Say I have two documents

```
/*1*/
{
"id":1,
"name":"natty",
"subject_enrolled":"english"
}
/*2*/
{
"id":2,
"name":"natty",
"subject_enrolled":"science"
}
```

Ideally, it should have been same document, with subject_enrolled being an array having both subjects. But for some reason, I maintained my data flat like this. 
Now, I want to write a query which will retrieve all students who have enrolled for both "english" and "science".

I tried the below query:

```
db.students.find({"subject_enrolled":{"$in":["science", "english"]}})
```

But that is wrong, coz if any student who registered for only science will also be in the result. I cannot use "$all", as both science and english are in two different documents.

Is there a way to achieve this easily and effectively?

Comment: Since there are no joins in mongo you cannot do a direct query for it. How about using the aggregation framework?. Group by id, use $addToSet to add all the subject and then use the match phase with an $all ?

Comment: @IshanSoni Thank you Ishan for you view. Yes. I tried aggregation. I have given the query I tried below here. But I am worried about performance. Is there any other way possible?

Comment: I cannot think of doing it any other way. Wait for others to respond meanwhile beware about some limitations of the aggregation pipeline. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/#result-size-restrictions

Comment: @IshanSoni there is [JOIN in MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

Comment: Thanks @SSDMS Never knew this stage existed :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I could think of now is to use an aggregate.

```
db.students.aggregate([{"$group":{"_id":"$name", "subject_enrolled":{"$addToSet":"$subject_enrolled"}}}, {"$match":{"subject_enrolled":{"$all":["english", "science"]}}}])
```

This satisfies my condition perfectly.

But I am worried about performance only. If I have say 10,000 documents, worst case I have all documents are for individual students and the querying Param is also a single value, then I will be aggregating for no good!

Mongo experts, please share your views on my situation.

Comment: @SSDMS Thank you pointing out about $lookup. But, I am not sure, how $lookup can help me in my condition. Can you please help me understand if $lookup can help me in the above problem?

Comment: `$lookup`  can't help here. And like I said, you are doing it right already.